# How to restrict specific size on the basis of mimetype of file in multer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

How to restrict specific size on the basis of `mimetype` of file in `multer`? I want to give different sizes for different `mimetype`. like I want to give 2 mb size for png or jpg and 20 mb for mp4...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mutter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)'s `fileFilter` and `callback(null, false)` to refuse files. To have different accepted sizes for different image types, you can do it like so:

```js
const maxSizePng = 1 * 1000 * 1000;
const maxSizeJpg = 2 * 1000 * 1000;

const upload = multer({
  dest: 'uploads/'
  fileFilter: function (req, file, callback) {
    if (file.mimetype == "image/png" && file.size > maxSizePng) {
      callback(null, false);
    }
    if (file.mimetype == "image/jpg" && file.size > maxSizeJpg) {
      callback(null, false);
    }
    callback(null, true);
  },
});
```

Comment: But we can't access file size inside Filefilter function of multer

Comment: How so? Are you getting an error?